# Are OpenID URL paths being lowercased?

Tags: support, openid

One of my OpenID URLs contains uppercase characters in the path, yet "my logins" displays it as all lowercase. Is this purely visual? And if not, could this cause problems at some point?

Comment: Assuming uppercase in the path *after* the domain, right? (Domain names are not case sensitive; but the remaining part of the URL indeed is, on many servers.)

Comment: Yes, I updated the question to clarify this, thanks.